# Find arc length of tractrix

Tags: derivatives

I found the equation for tractrix is

$a \cdot \operatorname{arccosh} (\frac{a}{x}) - \sqrt{a^2-x^2}$

Now I'd like to find the arc length via $\int_a^b \sqrt{1+ f'(x)^2} dx$

Am I right with derivative $f'(x)$:

$f'(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{x^2}-1}}+\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$ ?

Comment: You should not ask these type of questions here. You could easily check your answer on wolfram alpha. See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5Barccosh(a%2Fx)-sqrt(a%5E2-x%5E2),x%5D for example.

Comment: MathJax hint:  you can use \arccos for arc cosine.  When the function is not built in you can use \operatorname {arccosh} to get the same effect-proper font and spacing

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=a \cdot \operatorname{arccosh} \left(\frac{a}{x}\right) - \sqrt{a^2-x^2}$$
$$f'(x) = -\frac{a^2}{x^2 \sqrt{\frac{a}{x}-1} \sqrt{\frac{a}{x}+1}}+\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=$$
$$=\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}-\frac{a^2}{x \sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\frac{x^2-a^2}{x \sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\frac{\left(x^2-a^2\right) \sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{x \left(a^2-x^2\right)}=$$
$$=-\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{x}$$

Arc length $$\int_c^d \sqrt{1+\left(-\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{x}\right)^2}\,dx=\int_c^d \frac{a}{x}\,dx=a\log\frac{d}{c}$$

Hope this helps